# sql-server-2008 R2-split-time-intervals-given-by-starttime-endtime-at-selected-point

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table has following data

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStudentSchedulingRecord(
seq_id int identity(1,1),
    Student_ID int ,
    PeriodNumber int ,
    CPStartTime datetime ,
    CPEndTime datetime ,
    DateItem datetime ,
    FirstSegmentEndTime datetime,
    SecondSegmentEndTime datetime
)
```

Now

```
Insert Into #TempStudentSchedulingRecord
    values(2730,1,'1900-01-01 07:25:00.000','1900-01-01 08:20:00.000','2010-10-05 00:00:00.000','2015-05-27 09:45:00.000','2015-05-27 16:00:00.000')

Insert Into #TempStudentSchedulingRecord values(2730,1,'1900-01-01 08:25:00.000','1900-01-01 10:00:00.000','2010-10-05 00:00:00.000','2015-05-27 09:45:00.000','2015-05-27 16:00:00.000')

Insert Into #TempStudentSchedulingRecord values(2730,1,'1900-01-01 10:05:00.000','1900-01-01 11:35:00.000','2010-10-05 00:00:00.000','2015-05-27 09:45:00.000','2015-05-27 16:00:00.000')
```

Now Here The firstSegmentTime is same in all rows. I want To find The Total minutes scheduled before First segment End and classes included in first segment.
Similarly find the The Total minutes scheduled between First segment End time and second segment end time and classes included in first segment.

Here the Period 2 resides both segments.. How can I calculate total minutes scheduled before first segment and second segment.

Desired Output is

```
Student Period  CPStartTime         CPEndTime           DateItem            FSET                SSET
2730    1       01/01/00 08:25 AM   01/01/00 10:00 AM   10/05/10 12:00 AM   05/27/15 09:45 AM   05/27/15 04:00 PM
2730    2       01/01/00 08:25 AM   05/27/15 09:45 AM   10/05/10 12:00 AM   05/27/15 09:45 AM   05/27/15 04:00 PM
2730    2       05/27/15 09:45 AM   01/01/00 10:00 AM   10/05/10 12:00 AM   05/27/15 09:45 AM   05/27/15 04:00 PM
2730    3       01/01/00 10:05 AM   01/01/00 11:35 AM   10/05/10 12:00 AM   05/27/15 09:45 AM   05/27/15 04:00 PM
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results as a table *in the question*.  Showing your sample data in a table format is also helpful.  The `insert` statements are useful, but a SQL Fiddle is even better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, I believe that providing ddl + dml is better then a link to SQL fiddle, as it suffers from a lot of downtime, and not everybody can access it (try it on your phone once, for example). Of course, the best option is to provide both.

Comment: using [`datediff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) doesn't cut it?